# Splitting a string like "__f__g_f_" Javascript

Tags: javascript

Say I have a string `__f__g_f_`

How can I achieve splitting it up to an array like `['__','f','__','g','_','f','_']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do:

```js
const str = '__f__g_f_'

const parts = str.split(/([a-z]+)/)

console.log(parts)
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that using capture groups in a regex with the split function preserves the matches. Cool thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's a neat feature :)

Comment: This regex is short and elegant but slow and not human-readable. 
Please check my answer below which shows that a plain simple javascript implementation is twice faster than regex.  Further reading: ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667015/is-regex-too-slow-real-life-examples-where-simple-non-regex-alternative-is-bett

Answer (score 1):

Split works at O(N) time complexity so you can write your own implementation and it is more readable and more maintainable

```js
const s = "__f__g_f_"
const array = []

let buffer = ""
for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

    if (s[i] === "_") {
        buffer += s[i]
        continue
    }

    if (buffer.length > 0) {
        array.push(buffer)
        buffer = ""
    }
    array.push(s[i])
}
if (buffer.length > 0) {
    array.push(buffer)
}
console.log(array)
```

Edit:

`(/([a-z]+)/)` is elegant but always be in the shoes of other developers. What does `(/([a-z]+)/)` mean at a glance ? Regex is like a compiled program, machine code. unless all developers are adept in regex, They are not self-documented. They require to be commented on. And there might have bugs in them, how can you trust `/([a-z]+)/` if it actually works without running the code? Seeing human readable code is always preferable. And finally, you may be surprised that regex can have weird time complexity, sometimes they jump to exponential. You don't know how they are implemented. Here, a simple plain and readable implementation is 100% faster than the regex.

```js
console.time('regex');
for (let i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {
  const str = '__f__g_f_'
  const parts = str.split(/([a-z]+)/)
}
console.timeEnd("regex")


console.time('plain_fast');

for (let i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {
  const s = "__f__g_f_"
  const array = []

  let buffer = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

    if (s[i] === "_") {
      buffer += s[i]
      continue
    }

    if (buffer.length > 0) {
      array.push(buffer)
      buffer = ""
    }
    array.push(s[i])
  }
  if (buffer.length > 0) {
    array.push(buffer)
  }
}
console.timeEnd("plain_fast")
```

```
regex: 10540.700ms
plain_fast: 4556.500ms
```

Comment: Your solution is longer, slower (I assume because of multiple string concatenations and `array.push` calls, but not sure - sorry if not, needs measurement) and is `O(N)` as well. It is far from "more readable" (for me, at least), and adds maintenance overhead (loop and 2 conditionals, so this can't exist without dedicated unit tests). Could you explain any benefits from using your solution?

Comment: I also don’t see how this should be preferable to the accepted answer, which is conceptually the most elegant imho

Comment: it is elegant but always be in the shoes of other developers. What does `(/([a-z]+)/)` mean at a glance ?  I don't like using regex in general. they are like compiled program, machine code. not self documented. They might have bugs in them,

Comment: it is elegant but always be in the shoes of other developers. What does `(/([a-z]+)/)` mean at a glance ?  I don't like using regex in general. they are like compiled program, machine code. not self documented. there might have bugs in them, @SUTerliakov how can you trust `/([a-z]+)/` if it actually work without running the code? I prefer seeing human readable code. regex needs to be united tested more than my code in my opinion because you never know what to expect in regex. you may be surprised that regex can have weird exponential time complexity. You don't know how they are implemented

Comment: If reader is used to regexes, this code is almost obvious for him: the regex solution was exactly what I expected (python's `re.split` does the same, for example). If you're concerned about this, you can add a comment: `// split, preserving all delimiters in-place`.  The regex is crystal clear in this case - will you unit test function returning `string.split('.')` to convert some.dotted.attrs.path to array of them? I won't, probably.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Please check my answer, I updated the code to illustrate that simple clean and human readable js is faster than regex. You never know what to expect in Regex. In this case, simple js is 100% faster than the regex which is twice slower

Comment: @TSR valid point, great! I'd still stick with elegant regex solution, because performance gain for one call is unnoticeable, but your solution is definitely not worth downvote. Sorry, I was almost sure that built-in regex should be faster than such manual processing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.split()` you can use **[`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** with a matching group in the regex, it will give you an array of all your wanted matches.

```js
const str = '__f__g_f_'
const parts = str.match(/(_+)|([a-z]+)/g)
console.log(parts);
```

```html
[
  "__",
  "f",
  "__",
  "g",
  "_",
  "f",
  "_"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom function without regex.

```js
function split(str) {
    let output = []
    let cur = ''
    for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if(str[i] !== '_') {
            output.push(str[i])
            continue;
        }
        
        cur += str[i]
        if(str[i + 1] !== '_') {
             output.push(cur)
             cur = ''
        }
    }
    return output
}

console.log(split('__f__g_f_'))
```